# Manipulate (Linux version of Mathematica)

Tags: front-end, manipulate, notebooks, linux, ubuntu

I'm runnning *Mathematica* 9 on Ubuntu 11.10. After installing CDF player I still have problem (most of time) with `Manipulate`. Only way I'm able to change value of a parameter is by manually entering a value into into an edit field (dragging the slider or pushing buttons doesn't work). Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? (Even simple `Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 5}]` doesn't work properly.)

Comment: What does this code do on your machine? `Slider[Dynamic[x],{0,1}]` then `Dynamic[x]`

Comment: First creates slider (like one in Manipulate) which I can not drag. Second returns `0.`

Comment: Did you modify Mathematica in any way (e.g. changing it to use system Qt libraries)?  What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: No - I'm using mentioned Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome 3.

Comment: Have you tried a different desktop environment?

Comment: I had the same problem (but using Ubuntu 12.04/x86_64). In my case, I guess it was a configuration-problem, since restarting once with `mathematica -cleanStart` helped. Did you try that?

Comment: Awesome @Dragos ! That fixed it.

Comment: I have the same issue. `mathematica -cleanStart` helps, but after some time the problem reappears.

Comment: I also have this problem. For me it appears only if Mathematica has been running during a hibernate or sleep. I don't know any way around this beyond restarting Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

By way of an answer:

> I had the same problem (but using Ubuntu 12.04/x86_64). In my case, I guess it was a configuration-problem, since restarting once with `mathematica -cleanStart` helped. Did you try that? – Dragos Mar 28 '13 at 0:13

The above answer solves the problem according to the OP:

> Awesome @Dragos ! That fixed it. – ipy Apr 6 '13 at 17:23

One user has doubts:

> I have the same issue. `mathematica -cleanStart` helps, but after some time the problem reappears. – Danvil May 10 '13 at 8:35

But the OP never returned to indicate there was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with this and I believe it was because I was using Open JDK.  I switched to the official Oracle JDK and that seemed to fix the problem.  However, now that I'm running Fedora 19 with OpenJDK 1.7.0_60 Runtime Environment (fedora-2.4.2.0.fc19-x86_64) I don't see this problem, at least not often.  So it might simply go away if you install Oracle's Java or upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu with a newer openjdk.

Comment: As far as I know Mathematica uses only the java it comes shipped with in `.../SystemFiles/Java/` so I don't think OpenJDK is the problem.