# Dynamic inside Button

Tags: dynamic, button, scheduling

This bit of code runs a little animation of a stochastic process:

```
 (* a random walk bm, its min and max  *)
 {bm, m, M} = {Table[Random[] - .5, {100}] // Accumulate, Min[bm], Max[bm] }

 (* plot of trajectory of bm up to i-th step *)
 traj[i_] := ListLinePlot[({Range[1, 100], bm} // Transpose)[[;; i]], 
    Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {m, M}}]

 (* animation using Clock *)
 q = Dynamic[r = Clock[{1, 100, 1}, 5, 1]; traj[r] ]
```

Next I'd like to use Button to run the animation. Something like

```
Button["Run", q]
```

but this doesn't work.

Eventually I'd like to have two buttons, "Repeat" and "Clear" like this:

```
x = {{0, 0}};   
min[x_] := (Sort[x, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]]  &])[[2]]; Column[ {Row[{Button["Repeat", 
 x = Append[x, { Random[], Random[]  }]], 
Button["Reset", x = { {0, 0}}]  }  ],
Dynamic[Show[{ ListPlot[x, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> None] , If[Length[x] > 1, 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{min[x], {min[x][[1]], -.1} }]}], {}],
 If[Length[x] > 1, 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{min[x], {0, min[x][[2]]} } ]}], {}]
 }]]}]
```

but instead of dots, I want to plot animated functions involving Clock.

Comment: "... part of a screen"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [`Trigger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trigger.html) ?

```
Panel@Column[{
   Dynamic@traj[r],
   Trigger[Dynamic@r, {1, 100, 1}]
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I have not! +1

Comment: @ Simon, Kuba, `Trigger` looks useful, but doesn't seem to be working on my Linux version.

Comment: @Kuba, oh you deleted your answer :-( It was interesting all the same.

Anyway, what I have is a function, like `q` in original post involving `Clock` `Dynamic` plots, and works perfectly well with Shift+Return. Now I want to wrap two buttons around it, one to evaluate, and one to repeat.

Ordinary functions like `Button["Do it", Sin[pi] // Print]` work fine, but not if there is a `Plot` or a `Dynamic`.

Could this be a Linux Mathematica issue? I know that `Manipulate` sliders never work in Linux. It's a real pain in the trousers, but I'm not switching to Windows just for this.

Comment: @zab I don't know why your `Slider` do not work. I think it is not normal behaviour :) but you have to talk with someone who works on Linux, not me. You can ask  separate question for this. About `Print` you can use `CellPrint` if you use Cell/BoxData/Toboxes earlier, take a look at documentation of those functions.

Comment: @Kuba, `Slider` issue is a known problem: 

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/manipulate-slider-unresponsive-after-suspend-in-linux

I will try `CellPrint`.

Comment: OK, so with my original definition of `q`, `Button["Run", q // CellPrint]` works, but when when I press it again, it creates a duplicate cell. How do I prevent this?