# Does a running evaluation continue after the PC wakes from sleep mode?

Tags: scheduling, asynchronous-processing, system-limitations

Are there any issues with running a process on *Mathematica*, putting the computer to sleep, and then waking the computer sometime later?

It seems to work just fine on my test process (appending data to a list), but I wanted to know if there may be complications with doing this that I can't predict.

Comment: I never had any problems with _computation_ with suspend/resume cycles, but beware of [small problems with interface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/manipulate-slider-unresponsive-after-suspend-in-linux).