# Manipulate in Linux and Mathematica v 10

Tags: manipulate, front-end

I am having issues with `Manipulate` in Mathematic 10.4.1 under Linux.
Simple:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 10}]
```

Result in frozen frontend, in the end the Abort Dynamic dialog appears. If I press Abort, the front end get accessible again, however, sometimes I get the following further error:

```
The front end encountered an error while processing a "NotebookPredictions" packet.
```

I believe on Windows the `Manipulate` works fine.
Can someone confirm this behaviour. It seems [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/manipulate-linux-version-of-mathematica) question is similar, but that was for Mathematica 9, I cannot believe that Wolfram would keep so ignorant about such a major bug.

### Update

I am experiencing the same issue in Windows version as well and this is strange, I would swear that it used to work.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this (Mathematica V10.4.1 or V11.0.0, under Linux Mint 17.3)

Comment: You should set the increment of `i` as fourth component of list in `Manipulate` definition.

Comment: @Rom38 you don't have to. If you don't, it can have any value in the range.

Comment: There is really no problem with the syntax, I can simply copy an example from help and I have the same problem.

Comment: In my case, `Manipulate` always produce the error-message when step is not defined. May be it appears because I use the counter for discrete data. But I guess, this is better to set the step in any case.